# Website login fails due to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track hitting status 400 error

Tags: web, post

Greetings all the I am trying to log into to the website world.wallstreetenglish.com, however logins fail on occasional laptops of our students because of the XHR track hitting an error message 400.

Other laptops are fine and the track POST goes with fine.

I tried turning off firewall, defender and any other security measures that may be blocking it, when I compare the header info with another header info that works (On another laptop) they are the same.

Please help.

**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMn8C.png)**

Here is also the RAW from a fiddle capture

POST https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track HTTP/1.1
Host: dc.services.visualstudio.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6086
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
Content-type: application/json
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sdk-Context: appId
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Accept: */*
Origin: https://world.wallstreetenglish.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://world.wallstreetenglish.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

[{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:21.815Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.RemoteDependency","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"6H/d7","ai.operation.name":"logout"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"id":"|6H/d7.iafZw","ver":2,"name":"GET /api/users/me","resultCode":"200","duration":"00:00:00.437","success":true,"data":"GET https://world.wallstreetenglish.com/api/users/me","target":"world.wallstreetenglish.com | cid-v1:653eb374-162f-483c-9426-af39d90b9193","type":"Ajax"}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:21.368Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.RemoteDependency","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"6H/d7","ai.operation.name":"signin"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"id":"|6H/d7.R92Nj","ver":2,"name":"POST /iamapi/api/connect/token","resultCode":"200","duration":"00:00:01.662","success":true,"data":"POST https://world.wallstreetenglish.com/iamapi/api/connect/token","target":"world.wallstreetenglish.com | cid-v1:093e14af-905b-4a16-bd58-bc1049e41f13","type":"Ajax"}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:21.384Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.Metric","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"6H/d7","ai.operation.name":"signin"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"PageVisitTime","kind":0,"value":58590,"count":1,"min":58590,"max":58590}],"properties":{"PageName":"undefined","PageUrl":"undefined"}}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:21.485Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.Pageview","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"6H/d7","ai.operation.name":"logout"},"data":{"baseType":"PageviewData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"Log in to the Student & Staff Portal | Wall Street English","url":"https://world.wallstreetenglish.com/login","duration":"00:00:00.501","id":"6H/d7"}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:23.474Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.Metric","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"8wdGB","ai.operation.name":"/login"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"PageVisitTime","kind":0,"value":2089,"count":1,"min":2089,"max":2089}],"properties":{"PageName":"undefined","PageUrl":"undefined"}}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:23.497Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.RemoteDependency","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"8wdGB","ai.operation.name":"signin"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"id":"|8wdGB.kCmEq","ver":2,"name":"GET /assets_config.json","resultCode":"200","duration":"00:00:00.045","success":true,"data":"GET ./assets_config.json","target":"world.wallstreetenglish.com","type":"Ajax"}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:23.625Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.RemoteDependency","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"8wdGB","ai.operation.name":"signin"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"id":"|8wdGB.JJpas","ver":2,"name":"POST /j/collect","resultCode":"200","duration":"00:00:00.132","success":true,"data":"POST https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j93&a=1027675425&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fworld.wallstreetenglish.com%2Flogin&dp=%2Flogin&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Log%20in%20to%20the%20Student%20%26%20Staff%20Portal%20%7C%20Wall%20Street%20English&sd=24-bit&sr=1536x864&vp=982x704&je=0&_u=SACAAEABEAAAAC~&jid=&gjid=&cid=1520644884.1633057036&tid=UA-126512654-2&_gid=1907831299.1633057036&_slc=1&z=416879078","target":"www.google-analytics.com","type":"Ajax"}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:24.239Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.Pageview","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"8wdGB","ai.operation.name":"signin"},"data":{"baseType":"PageviewData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"Wall Street English","url":"https://world.wallstreetenglish.com/login","duration":"00:00:02.104","id":"8wdGB"}}},{"time":"2021-10-01T03:11:24.240Z","iKey":"9a71604c-82c1-45fc-a21a-d682907b5184","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.9a71604c82c145fca21ad682907b5184.PageviewPerformance","tags":{"ai.session.id":"1E5gS","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:1.0.20","ai.user.id":"uO5SV","ai.operation.id":"8wdGB","ai.operation.name":"signin"},"data":{"baseType":"PageviewPerformanceData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"Wall Street English","url":"https://world.wallstreetenglish.com/login","duration":"00:00:02.104","perfTotal":"00:00:02.104","networkConnect":"00:00:00.004","sentRequest":"00:00:00.298","receivedResponse":"00:00:00.001","domProcessing":"00:00:01.374"}}}]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).